# How to check that the SSN is only a digit

Tags: java

I want to make sure that The **isValid** method checks for the following errors and throws a SocSecException
with the appropriate message.

1. Number of characters not equal to 11. (Just check the length of the
   string)
2. Dashes in the wrong spots.
3. Any non-digits in the SSN.
4. Hint: Use a loop to step through each character of the string, checking
   for a digit or hyphen in the appropriate spots

//SocSecException Class

```
public class SocSecException extends Exception
{
    public SocSecException (String error){
        super("Invalid the social security number, " + error);
        
    }
}
```

//SocSecProcessor Class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SocSecProcessor{
    
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name,SSN;
        String response;
        char answer ='Y';
        
        while(Character.toUpperCase(answer)== 'Y'){
            try{
                System.out.print("Name? ");
                name = input.nextLine();

                System.out.print("SSN? ");
                SSN= input.nextLine();

             if (isValid(SSN)){
             System.out.println(name + " With "+ SSN + " is Valid");
             }
            }
            catch (SocSecException e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            System.out.print("Conitnue? ");
            response = input.nextLine();
            answer = response.charAt(0);
        }
    }
    
    public static boolean isValid (String ssn) throws SocSecException{
        
        boolean v = true;
        int index = 0;
        
        if(ssn.length()!=11){
           throw new SocSecException("wrong number of characters"); 
        } 
        while (index < 11 && v){
            if(index == 3 || index == 6){
                if (ssn.charAt(3) != '-' || ssn.charAt(6) != '-'){
                    throw new SocSecException ("dashes at wrong positions");
                }
                else if (!Character.isDigit(ssn.charAt(index))){
                    throw new SocSecException ("contains a character that is not a digit");
                }
            }
            index++;
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
    
}
```

The problem is that even if the SSN was right it keeps showing the invalid message that the numbers are not digit!

Comment: Move the `else if` out to just before the `index++` so that it becomes an `else if` to the index check of 3 or 6. The issue is that you are getting the invalid message because you are checking for digits when you are also checking for dashes.

Comment: for the non-americans, you should probably clarify how a valid SSN looks like. instead of just copying the points from your homework. btw the check for dashes should probably be for charAt(index)

Comment: _The problem is that even if the SSN was right it keeps showing the invalid message that the numbers are not digit!_ In other words, your code contains a bug. Every programmer encounters bugs in her program. That's why we have debuggers. If you are using an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), like [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), for example, then it should have a debugger. You should learn how to use it and don't rely on _stackoverflow_ to serve as your debugger.

Comment: Don't unnecessarily abbreviate names. "SocSecException" should at least be "SocialSecurityException"; but "SocialSecurityNumberValidationException" would actually describe its meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `else if` from there to the outer condition.

```
while (index < 11 && v)
{
    if(index == 3 || index == 6)
    {
        if (ssn.charAt(3) != '-' || ssn.charAt(6) != '-')
        {
            throw new SocSecException ("dashes at wrong positions");
        }
    }
    else if (!Character.isDigit(ssn.charAt(index)))
    {
        throw new SocSecException ("contains a character that is not a digit");
    }
    index++;
}
```

Comment: Note that `ssn.charAt(3) != '-' || ssn.charAt(6) != '-'` would be more easily written as `ssn.charAt(index) != '-'`. Also, `v` is not changed, so no need to check in condition; and it's cleaner here to use a for loop.